# Convert type object to type array. Java

Tags: java, arrays, object

The following code is given for my assignment:

```
class AList<T> implements ListInterface<T> {

private T[] list; // array of list entries
private int numberOfEntries; // current number of entries in list
private static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 25;

public AList() {
    this(DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY);  // call next constructor
} // end default constructor

public AList(int initialCapacity) {
    numberOfEntries = 0;
    // the cast is safe because the new array contains null entries
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T[] tempList = (T[]) new Object[initialCapacity];
    list = tempList;
} // end constructor
```

My assignment is to create a method that returns true when the contents of two AList objects are the same. That is, they have the same number of items and each item in one object is equal to the item in its corresponding location in the other object. I am required to use the following meathod header:

```
public boolean equals (Object other)
{
//my code goes here
}
```

I tried this, but it's not working.

```
public boolean equals(Object other)
{
if (Arrays.equals(this.list, other))
return true;
else
return false;

}//end equals
```

other is of type Object. how do I make it an array?

Comment: `other` "should" be an instance `AList`.  You need to check for that first, then cast it and try an compare the arrays...

Comment: I'm guessing that somewhere in there you'd use a loop.  But maybe before that check that the two arrays are the same size.

Comment: Why are you converting to an array at all, instead of using [a sane `List#equals()` implementation?](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/AbstractList.java.html#511)

Comment: @MadProgrammer other would be an instance of AList. in the main method it would look something like this:

AList<Integer> testListA = new AList<Integer> ();
AList<Integer> testListB = new AList<Integer> ();

testListA.equals(testListB)

Comment: In that case, I think you have a problem, based on the code you've supplied, because `list` has `private` access, meaning you can't reference the field.  Does `AList` or `ListInterface` have any other methods for accessing the data??

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code to convert list into Object Array before compairing

```
public boolean equals(Object other)
{
Object listObj[]=list.toArray();
if (Arrays.equals(listObj, other))
return true;
else
return false;

}//end equals
```

Comment: `return Arrays.equals(listObj, other);` seems shorter. Or, if you want to reduce the method body to 1 line: `return Arrays.equals(list.toArray(), other);`

Comment: @Algorithmist
that will not work. Arrays.equals() requires two arrays for input. In your solution, "other" is still of type Object, therefore it will not compile.